# How to formulate the maximum?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

How Can I get maximum date based on underlined stories at every epic level using google sheets formulas? Here is an example
[image]

Max Date needs to be lookup back to main table.

Comment: What have you tried so far? It might make a difference using google-sheets or Excel. Please deselect one of the tags.

Comment: what is the expected result?

Comment: Above is the example where Finish Date highlighted in Yellow, Column B, is expected output.

Answer (score 0):

*You may try with:*

```js
=max(filter(B:B,regexmatch(A:A,"^Epic")))
```

Comment: This is giving the overall max but I want at every Epic level

Comment: It would help if you could share a sample sheet with *realistic*-demo data and expected output(**manually entered**) so as for us to get a clear picture & workout a solution. You may also use the [**anonymous blank sheet maker**](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeprZS3Al0n7JiVQIEiCi_Ad9FRXbpgB7x1-Wq6iAfdmVbWiA/viewform) provided by [*docs community forum*](https://support.google.com/) incase you do not wish to share a sheet from your google account.

Comment: Above is the example where Finish Date highlighted in Yellow, Column B, is expected output.

Comment: I can see 2 Epic's listed & both are highlighted yellow in the screenshot. so what does maximum mean here in the context?

Comment: Maximum at Epic level

Comment: If possible please do share a sample sheet(*as instructed in the above comment*) & we can check it out directly.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```cpp
=ARRAYFORMULA(
   LET(f,SCAN(,A2:A,LAMBDA(a,c,IF("Epic"=LEFT(c,4),c,a))),
       QUERY(
         {A2:A,IF(""<>B2:B,B2:B,MAP(f,LAMBDA(x,MAX(FILTER(B2:B,x=f)))))},
         "where Col1 is not null")))
```

[image]

Comment: Hey Thanks a lot for this one but it fails when I try to update the date for one of the stories. So lets say if I update E2 S2 from 13th May 2024 to 13 Jun 2024 then that being highest date amount stories of that Epic should give the date 13th June 2024 against Epic2

Comment: the formula works fine. https://imgur.com/a/v9yP0hN

Comment: Understood I need to make the B2 and B4 blank. It works. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: you can change `""<>B2:B` to `"Epic"<>LEFT(A2:A,4)` so the formula works also if the rows adjacent to "Epic" are not blank.

Comment: I want to look this max value up again back to main table. How can I avoid circular reference?

Comment: what do you mean by `I want to look this max value up again back to main table`

Comment: This is a subset  of the original data. I want to take these epic level dates back to main data.

Comment: This gives circular reference if I use the E column for lookup in B column. So Formula in B column which I want is: =IF(LEFT(B2,4)="Epic", vlookup(A2,D:E,2,false), )

Comment: I don't get what you're trying to do, sorry.

Comment: Okay simply how can I alter this formula to accomodate in Column B itself?

Comment: this is not possible. A range cannot have both manually entered results and results generated via a formula. You can copy the result of the formula and Paste Special -> Paste values only over column B.